# What does " var x = "theBomb" in megalomaniac; " do?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I'm working through JavaScript koans from GitHub  and got stopped by this one:

```
it("should have the bomb", function () {

  var hasBomb = "theBomb" in megalomaniac;

  expect(hasBomb).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
});
```

I've never seen the construction

```
var x = "y" in object;
```

before and I'm not sure what it is doing.
The koan expects hasBomb to be true.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is comprised of two parts:

1. `"theBomb" in megalomaniac;` checks whether a property named `theBomb` exists in the Object `megalomaniac` (or in its prototype chain). See [in Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
2. `var hasBomb = "theBomb" in megalomaniac;` assigns the value of that check (either `true` or `false`) to the variable `hasBomb`.

Example:

```
var megalomaniac = {theBomb: 'boom'};

var hasBomb = "theBomb" in megalomaniac;

console.log(hasBomb); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

`a in b` checks whether object `b` has property `a` or not.

**Note:** It also checks it through prototype chain.

If you don't need to check through whole prototype chain, you could use this code.

```
b.hasOwnProperty(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

> // Custom objects
>   var mycar = {make: "Honda", model: "Accord", year: 1998};
>   "make" in mycar  // returns true
>   "model" in mycar // returns true

so in your case, the object `megalomaniac` may or may not have the property `theBomb` and this code (probably a unit test of some sort) is checking for that.